# Where can I find emacs major modes for Rexx or z/Assembler?

Tags: emacs, rexx, major-mode

I'm in the process of moving a lot of my editing to emacs (currently 23.3.1).

I'm looking for (two separate) major modes for emacs that will handle Rexx and z/Assembler, preferably including syntax highlighting, code and structure completion, and code formatting.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obsolete mode for Rexx can be found at [Emacsattic](https://github.com/emacsattic?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=Rexx). This was last updated towards the end of 2011.

There is an even older (2007) mode called Z390-mode that can be downloaded from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/z390-mode/?source=directory), that was written for s370-Z900.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I have forked the [Emacsattic](https://github.com/emacsattic/rexx-mode) to [pierre-rouleau/rexx-mode](https://github.com/pierre-rouleau/rexx-mode) and added some features:

- imenu/speedbar support to list REXX files and their defined procedures,
- move to next/previous procedure.

If anyone knows if there's a home for the original code, let me know; i'd like to contribute the changes to that code if possible.